# how to empty the jqgrid grid after sending the data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid, grid

I have a jqgrid and after sending those grid records to server I want to empty the grid ...I am trying with reload but its not working...i am using it under complete ...but its not empty the grid grid instead it show me the same data...
how can I achieve it ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably [clearGridData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method is what you need. If you use some custom data binding to elements of the grid you will have to set [deepempty:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option of jqGrid also, but typically it is not needed.